# Use Richardson Extrapolation to compute the function

Tags: numerical-methods

A regular n sided polygon inscribed in a circle of diameter one has the circumference as

> c<sub>n</sub> = 2 n Sin( Π / n )

put h=1/n

How can i show whether c(h) = c<sub>1/h</sub>  satisfies the assumption for **repeated Richardson extrapolation**

Also i need to calculate c<sub>2</sub> , c<sub>3</sub> , c<sub>6</sub> (which i can do ) and perform repeated Richardson Extrapolation

My knowledge in Richardson Extrapolation is very bad and i have got no idea how to do it

So please help

Comment: The question in the link do appear to  be like one given here but only in terms of what is given.  But the core question asked is very diffferent.  I request you guys to look in the problem again and remove the duplicate mark from it

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question addresses your question as well. It shows how to derive a new asymptotic error expansion from the original. This is the information you need to justify repeated Richardson extrapolation. If your question is about how to combine specific values $c_j$ for $j=2,3,6$ to estimate $\pi$, then an answer is possible, but will not involve what is traditionally labeled as repeated Richardson extrapolation.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Taylor's formula:
$$
C(h)=\frac 2h \sin (\pi h) = \frac 2h \left((\pi h)- \frac{(\pi h)^3}{3!} + O(h^5)  \right) = 2 \pi + \frac{2 \pi^3}{3!} h^2 + O(h^4)
$$

In general, when you are approximating a quantity $C^*$ by a formula like
$$
C^* = C(h) + a_0 h^{k_0} + O(h^{k_1}),
$$

the extrapolation based on $C(h)$ and $C(h/t)$ is given by
$$
R(h,t)=\dfrac{t^{k_0} C(h/t)-C(h)}{t^{k_0}-1}
$$

and in fact
$$
C^* = R(h,t)+O(h^{k_1})
$$

In your case, the extrapolation based on $c_3, c_6$ is given by
$$
C^* \approx \dfrac{2^2 c_6-c_3}{2^2-1}=\frac 43 c_6-\frac 13 c_3
$$

You can see the advantage of this procedure just by computing the errors:
$$
|2 \pi -C(1/3)|\approx 1.09, \quad |2 \pi -C(1/6)|\approx 0.28, \quad |2\pi - R(1/3,2)| \approx 0.015
$$

Comment: The asymptotic error expansion is central to Richardson's technique, but your answer does not address the core issue: how should the OP combine different approximations.

Comment: @CarlChristian I only mentioned the expansion because the next step is a direct use of the formulas but I'll complete my post.

Comment: @PierreCarre please complete the post.If it gets complete i will accept the answer

Comment: @RoushanSingh I think it is complete.